# Archilogic material preset choices in 3d.io viewer

Tags: aframe, archilogic, 3d.io

I would like to create a web app that lets the user choose between different presets for floors and walls in an archilogic 3D scene.

https://spaces.archilogic.com/model/template/new?modelResourceId=f67ffde0-278e-11e4-9f8c-7dda0d61ae4a&mode=edit&view-menu=camera-bookmarks&main-menu=interior&logo=false

Just like in this editor, however, I need the materials menu to be simpler (user chooses from different preset textures which were uploaded earlier by the admin with the corresponding diffuse, spec, normal, and alpha maps).

I was browsing through all the repos of archilogic but couldn't find the source code of the 3D editor in order to make it simpler.

Does anyone know if it's available, if not, which direction should I be headed in order to develop such an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature that still is on the roadmap and not done yet, but there are ways to accomplish something similar.

**So above all, the following description is due to all this not being ready and polished yet. It's an experimental way of getting to your goal.**

Let's break this down.

## Predefined materials

Archilogic has a long list of pre-defined materials right now that you can pick from. They're agnostic to the type of architectural element, so you can use any material on any element. [Here is the list of available materials](https://gist.github.com/AVGP/9ff552677e3a12a4ee6049cb0a078959).

### Floor & ceiling

Floors and ceilings are contained in a single element with an `io3d-floor` component.

So assuming you've got your floor and ceiling in the `elem` element, you can do the following to select a **pre-defined** material:

```
elem.components['io3d-floor'].data.material_top = 'wood_parquet_oak';
elem.components['io3d-floor'].update()
```

this will change the floor material to the given pre-defined material, in this case "wood_parquet_oak". For the ceiling material, change `material_top` to `material_ceiling`.

### Walls

Walls work pretty much the same, but the properties are `material_front` and `material_back` instead of `material_top` and `material_ceiling`.

### Other architectural elements

For other elements, you can probably work it out by looking what is available as properties in `.data` of the associated component (e.g. `io3d-wall` for walls).

## Custom materials

This is a little harder to get right as there's a bunch of properties involved in making a custom material.

Assuming you have uploaded textures somewhere, you'd define the material like this:

```
elem.components['io3d-floor'].data.material_top = {
  mapDiffuse: "https://example.org/texture.hi-res.gz.dds",
  mapDiffusePreview: "https://example.org/texture.lo-res.jpg", 
  mapDiffuseSource: "https://example.org/texture.source.jpg"
}
```

You can also give it additional parameters, such as `size: [3,3]` scaling the texture to cover 3x3 meters in the model before repeating itself or passing normal maps or specular maps, but I exclude these for brevity.

Note: You can use this kind of material definition for anything that also accepts the pre-defined materials mentioned above. **It's important to follow the naming convention** and you need to have a gzipped DDS texture available as well as JPEG versions.

The 'Source' image is optional, but the other two have to be present or it won't work.

Summing it up: This functionality isn't fully ready yet (as you can tell by the quite contrived way of getting this to work) but this workaround will do until a better way is going to be available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed reply. I can now see why it's still on its way to be polished. I'm still new to a-frame, I have been trying to search for a resource where I can learn how to select an element using the mouse cursor but couldn't find any.